# Selenium testing, of the URL that sits on an internal ip address, with the sauce-lab driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, saucelabs

I have tried this kind of scenario, and I guess the dns can not resolve the ip of the given URL and nothing happens. Is there a way to work around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Sauce Connect.

Without Sauce Connect, Sauce Labs sessions can only access publicly accessible sites.

When you use Sauce Connect, then it creates a tunnel between Sauce Labs and the machine on which you are running Sauce Connect. It is analogous to how you can create a tunnel with `ssh`. You need to download Sauce Connect and then start it with a command like:

```
[...]/bin/sc -u <Sauce Labs user Id> -k <Sauce Labs API key>
```

The API can can be found in your Sauce Labs dashboard, in the "User Profile / User Settings" section.

Here is the [documentation](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Basic+Sauce+Connect+Proxy+Setup) on Sauce Connect for a basic setup.

Comment: Thanks for the message.  So other than this extra step, is there anything change I need to make on the test case level ?    Plus, when I was to run this "sc" cmd, I got such failure, `27 Sep 16:51:52 - error querying from https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/xxx... ?full=1, error was: {"message": "Not authorized"}. HTTP status: 401 Unauthorized
27 Sep 16:51:52 - Sauce Connect could not establish a connection.
27 Sep 16:51:52 - Please check your firewall and proxy settings.
`,  is that means I need to do some config on my testing host ?

Comment: The error you get with `sc` is what you get if you do not pass correct credentials. Check that you are passing the correct values for `-u` and `-k`. Make sure the value you give to `-k` is the *API key* (not your password). I've always worked with the basic setup I linked to but there may be some scenarios where you need more configuration. I cannot tell whether it is the case for you.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I was passing the ENCRYPTED sauce-lab key value. Once that is cleared, the "sc" cmd was up and running successfully.  But somehow, it does not solve my original issue, the URL still can not be located.